# Android keyboard api

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

Does android expose an API or somesuch for the development of thirdparty keyboard applications? There are several existing apps which can replace the default input methods, however I cannot seem to find any information about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html) post for creating an IME