# Android Keyboard

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

How to add a new key in android keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to write your own input method editor (IME), perhaps cloning the existing one from the Android open source project. Then, you will need to install that IME in your phone. [Here is an article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html) covering some of the steps.