# how do I ceate a keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am creating an app that requires the user to type into an EditText. sometimes they need to type in a different language. the problem is, this language is not available on android, and I don't know how to customize my own keyboard. does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Comment: not exactly, because I don't even know where to start. I'm walking in the dark

Comment: The answers have a link to http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html ... I would say that's a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html

These guides are made for this.