# Custom inputType / key set for Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, textinput, android-input-method

I'm looking into changing bits and pieces of Android's input methods, to enter coordinates specifically.

The keys/characters needed are 1234567890.-:
When choosing numeric signed and decimal I have the first 12 covered, but can't get the : to be included or any other character that can take it's place (perfect would be to have a <kbd>°</kbd> key).

I've now written in input filter that filters those characters: it works but it ain't pretty. The main issue I have is that I can not get the keyboard to open on numbers side instead of the letters side.

Another option that I'd be very interested in would be to amend the existing phone type keypad to include my desired keys. It would remove a lot of clutter and make the remaining keys larger, thus making input easier.

Comment: In addition I'd like to add that it is possible: the Radar app is doing just that.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean writing your own custom keyboard?
If so you can refer this: [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Comment: I hope to avoid just that, instead use the default keyboard with only specific arbitrary keys enabled. So independent from the current fixed options that are built in.

Comment: I don't know any solution for that, except for writing custom keyboard