# File AndroidManifest.xml not found in LatinIME

Tags: android, eclipse, android-softkeyboard

I'm a n00b trying to create a custom soft keyboard similar to this post:

> [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

I have:

1. installed Eclipse
2. installed the Android SDK
3. cloned [LatinIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)
4. created a new Eclipse project from existing source [LatinIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

and Eclipse returns the error:

> "File AndroidManifest.xml not found in
>   LatinIME."

any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Click on *File* -> *New* -> *Android Project*, on the opened window select the radio button *Create project from the existing source* then reset the path to `C:/Desktop/Workspace` or to your default workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Is your androidmanifest.xml file blank? One time mine got completely wiped when creating a new project

Comment: Eclipse returns the error prior to creating the project. And as i created a new workspace for this activity, AndroidManifest.xml doesn't yet exist.