# Multiple language keyboard selection problem in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to implement arabic, spanish and french soft keyboard in my android application.If User prefers French language than French keyboard should open, if user prefers Arabic than arabic keyboard should get opened......and my application is developed in android 2.2. i want this to implement programmatically. Can any one help me out ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is that you write your own keyboard and inform it that you want a custom language.
This is a little time consuming as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android).