# Creating an Android Keyboard with Listview layout inside

Tags: android, xml, layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have been trying to modify the SoftKeyboard example to insert a custom layout of buttons, checkboxes, radiobuttons etc, but I was unable to do so. The keyboard shows as blank each time I try using it. I tried modifying `qwerty.xml` as well as `input.xml`, but no luck.

Is this even possible using the SoftKeyboard sample, or by any other means?

Comment: Still looking for an answer.. anyone attempted anything similar?

Comment: What are those checkboxes and radiobuttons for? Are they for options? If you want to customize the appearance and buttons, take a look at [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android).