# Gujrati Keyboard in android

Tags: android

i need to develop a Gujarati Keyboard  without rooting the device ,in my application ,i refereed  [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android/3480756#3480756)  ,  i could not get proper solution so please suggest me how to do this ....

Thanks