# I want to create my own software keyboard for android

Tags: android, android-keypad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

I want to create my own keyboard ( software)  for the android operating system can anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged as ``facebook-android-sdk``? :)

Comment: check this https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=active&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=custom%20keyboard%20for%20android&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=311bd0233f7d7f29&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=563

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "[Soft Keyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html)" example.
 Also look for Input Methods.