# modifing the android firmware

Tags: android, operating-system, rom

i want to make an application or more like a tweak for android 
i want to write some code that's gonna work on an android device and will do curtain actions based on an input from a Bluetooth device
this application needs to run in the background at all times (as if it was part of the device's operation system) 
and be getting input every second 
i need it to be able to bring up i custom keyboard i am gonna design and to set up a courser just like in a desktop which can be controlled by the application.

i read about something called a ROM and i dont know if thats what i am looking for.

i also know that the android operation system can be modified or replaced with another operation systems like the one called cyanogen .

i am a beginner and i have got some background in java

i tried creating an android app but i dont know how to make this thing work on the OS

i need someone to give me a very detailed explanation cause i know nothing about these stuff

Comment: [AOSP](http://source.android.com/) and [XDA-Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) are two great resources you can to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like your trying to make an App that takes Bluetooth input...

It doesn't sound like you need to edit the OS itself...

You need to set up the Android SDK to start development...
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html
1. Download the SDK
2. Install the Eclipse Plugin
3. Write the code, and run it on the emulator or your connected device(make sure debugging is enabled under Setting->Applications->Developer)

Here's some info on getting started w/ Bluetooth...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Since you want this to run all the time, I would look into Android Services also...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

You may want to also take a look at the Sample Projects included w/ the SDK after you download the SDK and set up your IDE and Emulator(or phone)...
http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Hope this helps clear some stuff up...

Comment: i want to edit the keyboard as well, have it look like a normal phone keyboard where you have the numbers and each number has 3 letters on it, i already have an algorithem that does the T9 function but i want this keyboard to show up every time the user wants to type.

i also want a virtual cursor to be displayed at all times .

are you saying this is all do-able as an application? an app could have the device replace the defult keyboard?

Comment: This post may be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android . Best of Luck!