# Create on-screen keyboard (android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to develop an on screen keyboard similar to the square app (image below)[image]

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me tips on which classes to focus on/ override for this. In particular, how do I associate the button clicks to the number input in the EditText field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android

Comment: I think the approach would be different considering this is not a keyboard which pops up/out when you click on the edittext. The keyboard is pretty much a view and is present on the screen always.

Comment: `KeyboardView`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11923742/503900

Answer (score 4):

Every [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) gets a [Tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag) with the associate value (for example `1`). Then, you use the [`android:onClick`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) to set all buttons to the same method (`input()` for example) in the activity.

This method will be called with the clicked view, which you can then use the [`getTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29)-method on to get the corresponding value:

```
// Will be called for every Button that is clicked
public void input(View v){
  Log.v("APP", "Pressed: "+v.getTag());
}
```

Organize the `Button`s in a [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) ([`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) might also be possible).