# How to detect touch inputs of an Android Popup Window

Tags: android

I'm developing android library that logs all touch inputs of an app.
I already managed to intercept all touch inputs for activities (and fragments), but not popups.

**how to detect touch inputs for new windows that pop up in the activity?**

The following code shows how I intercept all touch inputs for a activity window.

Inside of `Application.onCreate()` I call `Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()`, and register following callback:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedState: Bundle?) {    
    val localCallback = activity.window.callback
    activity.window.callback = object : ActivityWindowCallbackWrapper(activity, localCallback) {
        override fun dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            //over here I can log all touch input    
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)
        }

        override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
            //here I can detect that some popup has popped up 
            //if hasFocus == false it means that some other window has focus -> probably popup 
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
         }
     }
}
```

This code intercepts all touch events for an activity window and it recognizes when a different window is focused (Another Window pops up), but I don't know how to register the callback for the newly focused window.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19776489/4687433) is a great example on how to detect all root views of an application, but I can not register any callbacks on them.