# Develop soft keyboard IME

Tags: android

I'm looking to develop a custom IME/softkeybard for android. I've seen some information here on SO but some of the links are broken like in this answer:
[How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android/3480756#3480756)

Does anyone know of any examples of custom IME/soft keyboards or tutorials for reference?

Comment: It is in the `Android Samples`

Comment: `New > other > Android > Android sample project > Android x.x > SoftKeyboard` :)

Comment: I looked there but I didn't see a softkeyboard example under any android version, why would that be?

Comment: When i try to open the layout in the sample i get the following error, `The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView (Open Class, Show Error Log)`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the code which you are trying to run can only execute successfully on the devices having api version 15 or greater.

Devices having lower api version do no have the android.preference.preferenceFragment class.

Also there is  no activity in your manifest file..Actually system is trying to find ImePreference activity which is extending the PreferenceFragment and as this is not available so unable to find the activity which causes the crash.