# How to disable default keyboard from appearing and showing cursor in android oreo 8.0 ?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am developing one app and I have show custom keyboard, 
I need to disable the android default keyboard from appearing and also cursor should be display when we click on that edittext.

I have follow below links (selected answers) but they didn't work for android 8.0

that code is worked to hide the keyboard from appearing but didn't show the cursor.

> [Android Edit Text Cursor Doesn't Appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282882/android-edit-text-cursor-doesnt-appear?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
>
> [Android: Disable soft keyboard at all EditTexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803193/android-disable-soft-keyboard-at-all-edittexts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#)

can any one know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for above question.

I have implement my custom keyboard (view with numbers) to input the numbers only in EditText.

I have used below function set for every edittext I used in screen.

```
fun disableSoftInputFromAppearing(editText: CustomEditText) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {

        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)
        editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
        editText.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
        editText.setOnClickListener {
            hideKeyboard()
        }

        try {               
            val f = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes")
            f.isAccessible = true
            f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor)
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        }

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
        editText.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
        editText.setOnClickListener {
            hideKeyboard()
        }
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true)
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ) {
            editText.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
            editText.isCursorVisible = true
            editText.setTextIsSelectable(true)
        } else {
            editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)
            editText.isFocusable = true
        }

        try {
            val f = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes")
            f.isAccessible = true
            f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor)
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            ignored.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

EditText in layout file

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
    tools:text="0" />
```