# EditText Keyboard Inputtype issue

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext

Which `EditText` Keyboard `Inputtype` combinaison can help me getting the following view. I try several issue but nothing. May be someone among you does already face this problem.

**What i want to get is Numerics on the top and the possibility to switch to symbols and letters**

***What i want to get if a use touch the EditText must be as following***
[image]

Comment: Get what "following view"? Also, what did you try, you say several things but there is no code...?

Comment: @TronicZomB sorry just forget to attach the image

Comment: check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android

Answer (score 1):

You may add the following attribute to your `EditText` in xml.

```
android:inputType="text|number"
```

However, some of the characters you input will not be appear - those which conflict with type *number*, like **@ = !** etc.

And in order to get search button (on bottom-right) in your virtual-keyboard, you may use:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

---

Update
Add the following to your EditText's xml and it will get you all the characters available in the keyboard under number inputmode:

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789.@#$&amp;*-=()!&quot;':;/?"
```

If you want to support more characters then simply append their **html name** in *android:digits*.

Comment: This didn't help. He just give me what i have already. But thanks

Comment: exactly what type of input do you want? numeric only?

Comment: Not numeric only. Numerics on the top and the possibility to switch to symbols and letters

Comment: See my updated answer. It will get you numeric and characters.

Comment: are you using stock keyboard or a custom one? because the implementation may vary among them. At my side(on emulator), it exactly works as expected.

Comment: it does show alphabetic keyboard if selected, but doesnt allow to insert such characters

Comment: i'am using the stock keyboard one

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:inputType="PutHereNestedInputType"
        />
```

[InputTypes](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) 
Hope it's help.

Comment: The only interesting thing was not answered.