# How to create custom keyboard using LUA and Corona?

Tags: keyboard, lua, coronasdk

There are some way to create custom keyboard code for iOS by Objective-C like [this.](https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards)

And some one for Android by Java like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

So, Is it possible to create custom keyboard for Android or iOS by LUA in Corona ?

Can we integrate it to system keyboard of Android ?

Please guide me some ways, tutorial links or sample code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to use the keyboard outside of the app then using Corona does not make sense. You would have to get the Enterprise version and then code it in iOS native an Android native then integrate it into Corona and even then I'm not sure its possible.

If you are making an app where keyboard is only to be used inside that app you can create an onscreen keyboard:

http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/onscreenkeyboard
https://www.developer.coronalabs.com/blog/coronageek/hangout-highlights-writing-a-custom-keyboard-for-spelling-test/