# Adding my own keyboard instead of default keyboard in Android device as input

Tags: android, keyboard, settings

I have developed one android keyboard. It's working properly as
separate app on any device. Now I need to show my app in:

> (Setting->Input)

Below image shows external keyboard added in device:

[image]

As you see in image Android keyboard is default.

> Example: Swiftkey 3 is added externally.

But I don't know how to add my own keyboard so I can choose this?

Comment: "Its working properly as separate app on any device" -- what does this mean? Did you implement an `InputMethodEditor` and `InputMethodService`?

Comment: No i didn't i have tried using reference as given below but getting some problem..

Comment: @CommonsWare i added InputMethod it showing my keyboard option in settings as shown in above image but when i want to replace my custom keyboard with built in device keyboard it gives me error....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html). Then continue with this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android/3480756#3480756%3E), as stated there:

Some tips:

- Read this tutorial: [Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)
- clone this repo: [LatinIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android/3480756#3480756%3E)

An inputMethod is basically an Android `Service`, so yes, you can do HTTP and all the stuff you can do in a `Service`.

You can open `Activities` and dialogs from the `InputMethod`. Once again, it's just a `Service`.

[Here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices/)'s another tutorial on the topic. I hope all this is helpful for you.

Cheers

Comment: i have already used this reference but not getting solution, have you successfully implemented this help so your keyboard will be running from Settings, not as separate app.

Comment: Which reference did you use? Did you take a look at the tutorial below ?

Comment: @Aniket - and this problem is ?

Comment: it is working without any error on emulator, and also if i run my app using apk file on any remote android device it is running successfully, but you know my app is no more user app it has to work as system app by replacing in-built keyboard, thats why ,i have only changed my android Menifest.xml file noting else......

Answer (score 4):

You have to create [InputMethodService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)... and just add below code in `Menifest.xml` file

```
<service android:name="FastInputIME"
        android:label="@string/fast_input_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
```

**Permisson:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"/>
```

Comment: Hi @CapDroid i have used xml configuration as you told above, so my app is successfully showing in settings option in android device, but when i want to switch from android default keyboard to my custom keyboard i am getting error like this "Unfortunately MyKeyboard has stopped". Do you have any about this? I have already posted my problem in detail on SO but not getting any response...please help me.....

Comment: @Aniket its means something error in your application.. check logcat error.

Comment: you know @CapDroid now my app in system app working on remote android device so how can i check logcat....

Comment: yes i have checked it is working properly on my emulator as well as on device after changed code.....

Comment: permission is not necessary