# get pressed key and throw another key in android

Tags: android, keyboard, keylogger, persian

i want to make an android app that works in background and get's what key is pressed in keyboard and throw Equivalent of it in another language,for example persian or arabic.
how can i do this?
thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot create a standard Android app for this, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. There may be tricks for accomplishing this on a rooted Android device (e.g., custom USB HID driver).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you can write such APP, this would violate lots of security measures in android. But you can write your own custom soft keyboard:

[How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

user will have to choose your keyboard explicitly in settings. You will be able to do all the translations inside your keyboard.

Comment: but i want to make this app for physical keyboard.

Comment: From what I know, you can do it but only inside your own app (with GUI, TextViews, ...), you cant just intercept what user enters in web browser, those might be bank login/passwords etc.