# Android keylogger with default keyboard(google)

Tags: android, keyboard, keylogger

I've been searching a way to create a keylogger that uses a default keyboard in android devices such as Google keyboard, but I found no idea with that.
Is there any way I can do that without installing a new keyboard?

I've seen some source in [Github](https://github.com/tomgersic/AndroidKeyLogger) and it uses softkeyboard. That keyboard's UI is not good. If we can't get a keylogger without installing a new keyboard, just give me the keyboard UI like Google keyboard

Comment: "Is there any way I can do that without installing a new keyboard?" -- hopefully not, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Similar Ques [Android Key logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245185/android-key-logger)

well for soft keyboard to appear, you can use

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To close it you can use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```