# Is it possible to make an Android keylogger which works in the background in working time?

Tags: java, android

A company asked me today that if I could develop a keylogger inside their company application which logs what their workers do in working time with their company phones. They suspect that not every employee works hard enough.

Well I know it's not ethical but I got curious whether it is at all possible? I think Android has enough security feature to make it stop an app like this. I saw some keylogger features on GitHub but they only log inside the app, not outside the other applications.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: It's possible, and it has already been answered. You make use of Android's accessibility APIs. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245185/android-key-logger

Comment: It's also worth noting that unless the application is a system level application, it will need user approval before running. The permission for Accessibility API is `BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach you might be able to take would be to develop a fork of the Keyboard, and force users to use that keyboard via a Device Administrator Policy. However, as previously mentioned, this might be in violation of a whole host of employee data protection laws.

Custom Keyboard Creation Tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615