# Android: how to know exactly via accessibility service whether user is typing or not?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

How to know exactly via accessibility service whether user is typing or not?
Users may type via soft keyboard or hardware keyboard, so the soft keyboard may not be visible, and  the focus change to an editable widget not mean user is typing.

Comment: please check this answers right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245185/android-key-logger

Comment: Would you like to hook keyboard events only for your app or globally?

Comment: I want to hook keyboard events globally