# Get text from keyOutputText android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Hi I am developing a custom keyboard and I used android:keyOutputText="" in keyboard xml. How to get that text within java class? I only found how to use android:codes to use with decimal codes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Comment: it only shows how to use with android:codes decimal codes. I want to use keyOutputText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a try. You can catch `keyOutputText` in the `onText` method of your  overridden implementation of `OnKeyboardActionListener`. Like this:

```
public class MyOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {
    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        // handle key code
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "input text: " + text);
    }

    @Override public void onPress(int primaryCode) { }
    @Override public void onRelease(int primaryCode) { }
    @Override public void swipeLeft() { }
    @Override public void swipeRight() { }
    @Override public void swipeDown() { }
    @Override public void swipeUp() { }
}
```

It seems keys with `keyOutputText` setting won't trigger `onKey` method when pressed.