# how to make custom keyboard with multiple language..?

Tags: android, chat, custom-keyboard

I want to make custom keyboard in my app that supports multiple languages. By clicking the language button, it shows a particular language keyboard and display it in chat.

Comment: Then you explain to him why its a bad idea.  That's what a professional is supposed to do, not blindly implement a bad idea because he's told to.  That's how you write crappy apps and waste money.

Comment: @GabeSechan One application and valid use case for creating a custom keyboard would be for a kiosk device where only a very limited and locked down set of functionality is required. In this case, options like accessing keyboard settings, or even the ability to enter some characters may need to be restricted. For such a case, there might be licensing considerations with using a 3rd party keyboard. In this case the extra functionality might actually be the problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android

Comment: Specifically with regards to multiple language support, see "Creating an IME Subtype" in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#IMESubTypes

Answer (score 4):

Documentation exists on the official Android developer's website and deals with exactly this topic. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html.

Regarding **multiple language support**, there is a section in there titled "Creating an IME Subtype" that specifically deals with this. There are also multiple tutorials that deal with the creation of keyboard subtypes, such as [this one](https://blog.swiftkey.com/tech-blog-android-input-method-subtypes/). Further, [here is an example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/android-4.1.2_r2/java/res/xml/method.xml) of how the LatinIME's subtypes are defined (on Google's Android source code website).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some third party library like [Indic](https://github.com/smc/Indic-Keyboard)