# selection in android custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I wanna add 4 buttons to my custom keyboard (select all, cut, copy, paste)
but I couldn't find the way of doing that. I have tried the select all using this line of code

```
getCurrentInputConnection().setSelection(0,1000);
```

but it didnt work, so is there any help for doing these 4 buttons (select all, cut, copy, paste)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use registered `EditText` to you keyboard to do all (select, copy,cut,paste) you want with it like a regular `EditText`.

Here is [answer related to your question to help you understand how use the EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25590116/2979171)

And also you can learn more detail about custom keyboard from this [article](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) which is provided source code.