# How to disable Settings button of input fields in KIOSK mode

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-event, samsung-knox

I want to how is possible to disable Settings button of input fields in KIOSK mode ? I have read the KNOX and KIOS official doc and searched on Stackoverflow, but was not able to find a working solution.

Comment: Do you mean [the Settings icon](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00079092/) in the keyboard's toolbar?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: @qtmfld Is there a way to disable it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a workaround.

1. Choose and install [any other keyboard app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=keyboard&c=apps), which has no feature such as settings.
2. In the **Settings** app, add it to device's input methods and disable the others.
3. Restrict the **Settings** app, with [KNOX](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/restriction/RestrictionPolicy.html#allowSettingsChanges(boolean)) ( `allowSettingsChanges` ).

If your KIOSK requires high-level security, you can [develop your own input method](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method) to avoid malicious [keylogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) app. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480756/9298629), sample codes are available in [AOSP repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/).

Comment: In that case how can I make Google Chrome to use my own keyboard ?

Comment: All the apps including Google Chrome automatically use your own keyboard, if you select it as **Default keyboard** in the Settings app. [This article](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-change-terrible-keyboard-your-samsung-galaxy-phone) explains how to do it, and wrote "Your new keyboard choice will now be displayed every time a keyboard is needed in the system — the default keyboard will never appear."

Comment: Hmm, actually there is a way to do it even with native keyboard, but I do not understand how... however, thank you for your time my friend

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-configure/kiosk-Mode.htm) This might help ?

> **Additional Device settings (Knox 3.4 and above devices only)**

> Language and input Select the Language and input checkbox to display
> additional keyboard utilization settings for Knox 3.4 and above
> supported devices.
>
> Refer to the Show keyboard button On and Off options to display a
> keyboard button on the device navigation bar for an easier toggle
> between mobile device keyboard resources. Once set, refer to the Allow
> user to change setting option to either Allow device user keyboard
> changes, Do not allow user changes or Do not allow and hide setting
> from user.